# Problema SQL - Obtención de resultados no coincide con la solución planteada

Tags: mysql, sql, select, mariadb, join

Estoy estudiando **SQL**, y dentro de una serie de ejercicios me topé con uno que plantea 2 (dos) tablas. La primera Animals cuya estructura es "name, type, country_id" y la otra es Countries compuesta por las columnas "id, country". La primer tabla posee 5 registros por dafault, y la segunda tres registros.
El objetivo es insertar un nuevo registro a la tabla Animals y luego visualizar una nueva tabla cuyos resultados sean únicamente "name, type, country".

Luego de ingresar sin problema el registro, para visualizar los resultados hago lo siguiente:

**SELECT** Animals.name, Animals.type, Countries.country **FROM** Animals **INNER JOIN** Countries **ON** Animals.country_id = Countries.id **ORDER BY** country **ASC**;

Query que me devuelve:

```
--------------------------------------------
Candy  | Elephant  | India 
--------------------------------------------
Bert   | Tiger     | India 
--------------------------------------------
Vova   |  Bear     | Russia 
--------------------------------------------
Pop    |  Horse    | USA 
--------------------------------------------
Merlin |  Lion     | USA 
--------------------------------------------
Slim   |  Giraffe  | USA (registro que inserté yo)
```

EL PROBLEMA es que La plataforma que me propone esto, me solicita que los resultados sean estrictamente de la siguiente manera:

```
--------------------------------------------
Candy  | Elephant  | India 
--------------------------------------------
Bert   | Tiger     | India 
--------------------------------------------
Vova   |  Bear     | Russia 
--------------------------------------------
Slim   |  Giraffe  | USA (registro que inserté yo)
--------------------------------------------
Merlin |  Lion     | USA 
--------------------------------------------
Pop    |  Horse    | USA
```

Por culpa de esto, no puedo avanzar. ¿Qué otra alternativa existe, sabiendo que las tablas no las puedo alterar a mi gusto?

Capturas del ejercicio:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Tiene que haber un **criterio** para ordenar? ¿Cuál es ese criterio?

Comment: El enunciado indica: (1) Ha llegado un nuevo animal, con los siguientes detalles: nombre - "Slim" , tipo - "Giraffe" , country_id - 1. (2) Se requiere hacer una lista completa de los animales para los visitantes del zoológico. Escribe una consulta para obtener una nueva tabla con los campos de cada animal name, type y country, ordenados por country.  Cuando yo hago la query que indiqué, que es muy sencilla, dice la App que está mal. Que debe figurar en el orden especificado. Siendo que "Slim" debe aparecer después de "Bear".

Comment: Ya logré descifrarlo, el enunciado no lo dice, pero analizando los resultados que se piden se puede ver. Revisa la respuesta.

Comment: El único criterio que cuadraría con el resultado pedido sería un orden descedente del ID autoincremental del animal. No veo ninguna otra forma de poder ordenar así.

Comment: Algo así más o menos: `ORDER BY 
    Countries.country ASC, Animals.id DESC;` dando por hecho que la tabla `Animals` tuviera una columna `id` o como se llame, autoincremental, pues si analizas el orden en que están los animales en la primera imagen, es lo único que cuadraría.

Comment: Se cayó la aplicación y su correspondiente complidador... me acaban de informar desde la App. MIl gracias de todas formas. Por ende las respuestas que provee también son erróneas o van a presentar discrepancias...

Comment: Eso que propones es genial, porque SÍ resuelve dicha problemática. Pero la Aplicación nunca indica la columna ID. Recién con MariaDB lo hice y funciona, pero en la APP me señala eso que te menciono. Pero bueno, ya está resuelto, es problema de la plataforma.

Comment: Revisa la respuesta editada, es lo único que tendría sentido al pedirse unos resultados ordenados. Como es lógico, cuando se pide un orden tiene que ser en base a un criterio. Imagina que te piden eso en tablas con millones de registros, no te pueden decir, los quiero ordenados así porque sí y no puedes modificar las tablas. Tienen que darte un criterio y si no existe a nivel de las tablas, hay que definirlo de algún modo, pero siempre teniendo como marco un criterio para ordenar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Según el segundo resultado que se te pide, y viendo la primera imagen, el único criterio de orden posible sería:

1. Ordenar en orden ascendente por `country`
2. Ordenar en orden descendente por **una hipotética columna autoincremental** en la tabla `Animals` (imaginaremos que esa columna se llama `id`). Si ordenas por país primero y luego por id descendente tendrías:

---

```
name       Animal.id (hipotetico)    country
-------------------------------------------------
Bert                 5               India
-------------------------------------------------
Candy                1               India
-------------------------------------------------
Vova                 3               Russia
-------------------------------------------------
Slim                 6               USA
-------------------------------------------------
Merlin               4               USA
-------------------------------------------------
Pop                  2               USA
-------------------------------------------------
```

Entonces, la consulta sería así:

```
SELECT 
    Animals.name, 
    Animals.type, 
    Countries.country 
FROM Animals 
    INNER JOIN Countries ON Animals.country_id = Countries.id 
ORDER BY 
    Countries.country ASC,
    Animals.id DESC -- cambiarla por como se llame si no es id;
```

Comment: El problema, es que la solución "obligatoria" por parte de la plataforma tienen el siguiente orden: (1) Bert (2) Candy (3) Vova (4) Slim (5) Merlin (6) Pop. En el que tú me indicas, quedaría (1) Bert (2) Candi (3) Vova (4) Slim (5) Pop (6) Merlin. Eso que sugieres, también lo hice pero no sirve lamentablemente. Lo único que llego a pensar, es que la respuesta que debe coincidir con la que yo genere, esté mal.

Comment: No entiendo. ¿`Bert` debe ir primero? No es eso lo que dice la pregunta. Edítala y pon el orden en que debería ir, copia y pega las filas identadas para que se vea en forma de tabla.

Comment: Nono, el orden que espera la aplicación es que aparezca en 4to lugar Slim, en 5to Merlin y 6to Pop. Dejemos de lado los primeros tres, que están bien. El problema surge con los resultados que espera la App.

Comment: Ahora entiendo menos. ¿A qué te refieres con solución "obligatoria" entonces? ¿Cuál es el orden en que deben quedar?

Comment: La solución que espera la aplicacion es que en la consola salga estrictamente: (1) Bert (2) Candy (3) Vova (4) Slim (5) Merlin (6) Pop. En ese orden. Nada más. Como indiqué debajo de la imagen que dejé adjuntada. Pero ni ordenando alfabéticamente, o de manera ascendente o descendente, coincide. ¿Me explico?

Comment: Ya, en la pregunta pusiste que `Candy` debería ir primero, por eso interpreté un orden descendente por `name`, pero tampoco cuadraría (se rompe con `Merlin`). **Debe haber un criterio**, ¿no hay más columnas en las tablas (aunque no tengan que salir en los resultados)?

Comment: No, básicamente es eso lo que indica el problema de cómo se debería ver una vez formulada la query. Subiré imágenes del mismo. Y vemos si está mal planteado, ya que la lógica se rompe, o es otra la cuestión.